# Combining 'class_weight' with SMOTE

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance, smote, imbalanced-learn

This might sound a weird question, but I could not find enough details in sklearn documentation about 'class_weight'. Can we first oversample the dataset using SMOTE and then call the classifier with the 'class_weight' option? As my testing set is highly imbalanced, I want to penalize misclassifications for minority classes. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried different classifiers using a combination of SMOTE and class_weight, the results are almost the same as using **only the SMOTE** approach, and this new config made almost no difference (which could be expected, following the logic behind the class_weigh approach).

PS: I have a pretty large dataset with multiple classes. This might result in different performance in different contexts.